# Configure uploadArchives task using gradle script kotlin

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to switch my libraries to Gradle Script Kotlin but I can't find a way to configure the uploadArchive task.

Here's the groovy kotlin script I'd like to translate:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
                    authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
            }

            pom.project {
                /* A lot of stuff... */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I've understood that it should start with

```
task<Upload>("uploadArchives") {
    /* ??? */
}
```

... And that's pretty much it !

AFAIU, in Groovy, the `Upload` task is "augmented" by the `MavenPlugin`.
How does it work in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0.11.x` (in Gradle 4.2) added better support for tasks that have *convention* plugins and better support for heavy Groovy DSLs. The full release notes are on [GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/releases/tag/v0.11.1). Here is a relevant snippet from those notes:

> **Better support for Groovy-heavy DSLs** ([#142](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/142), [#47](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/47), [#259](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/259)). With the introduction of the withGroovyBuilder and `withConvention` utility extensions. `withGroovyBuilder` provides a dynamic dispatching DSL with Groovy semantics for better integration with plugins that rely on Groovy builders such as the core `maven` plugin.

[Here is an example taken directly from the source code](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/75eff6bff118253852d5e040831caa7afd7136c3/samples/maven-plugin/build.gradle.kts#L10-L45):

```kotlin
plugins {
  java
  maven
}

group = "org.gradle.kotlin-dsl"

version = "1.0"

tasks {

  "uploadArchives"(Upload::class) {

    repositories {

      withConvention(MavenRepositoryHandlerConvention::class) {

        mavenDeployer {

          withGroovyBuilder {
            "repository"("url" to uri("$buildDir/m2/releases"))
            "snapshotRepository"("url" to uri("$buildDir/m2/snapshots"))
          }

          pom.project {
            withGroovyBuilder {
              "parent" {
                "groupId"("org.gradle")
                "artifactId"("kotlin-dsl")
                "version"("1.0")
              }
              "licenses" {
                "license" {
                  "name"("The Apache Software License, Version 2.0")
                  "url"("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt")
                  "distribution"("repo")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```